# Tailwind grid gallery, First column height is large causing whitespace

Tags: tailwind-css, gallery, masonry

Hi I'm designing a gallery with Tailwind and Vuejs. I'm having trouble creating a masonry type  effect in gallery either using flex or grid layout system.

The first image is the cover image and is double in height. In the image below the **whitespace must be covered with a image**.

[image: Image Gallery]

The 3rd picture instead of showing up on the right whitespace, it goes down to row 2.

My code is :

```
    <div id="Gallery" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
            <div class="gallery-img text-center shadow" :class="(index == 0)?'col-span-2 cover':''"  v-for="(img,index) in Images">
                <img class="w-full rounded-lg" :src="img.url" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-img bg-green-100 shadow add_button flex sm:justify-center ">
                <button type="button" class="btn ">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Styles are:

```
.gallery-img.cover{
    width:289px !important;
    height:289px;
}
.gallery-img{
    width:196px;
    height:141px;
}
```